# Java application Error while reading a csv file using openCSV CSVReader ... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, bounds, opencsv

I get an error in my Java application when i try to read a column from each line of my csv file

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

My code is like this using OpenCSV

```
    public void insertOjd(String fichierEntree) throws SQLException {
    try {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fichierEntree));


        String[] nextLine;

            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
             if (nextLine != null) {

                 System.out.println(nextLine[1]);                   
             }}....
```

Comment: Its likely that  you have a big line in the file, without any comma on it and so you would have only nextLine[0] created and when you try to refer index 1 you get this error

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an empty line or comment line in the CSV or something like that. The error means that there is no 2nd value on that row (nextLine[1] is the second value). Check your file and print nextLine[0] and you will see the mistake. nextLine[0] will contain the whole row.
Make sure you tell openCSV to use the poper separator, escape character etc.